# Update DIV using AJAX and PHP from information deriving from a text file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that grabs information from a text file and posts it into a table in similar fashion to what is shown below. The javascript function `getIV()` worked to do just that.

```
Tag Name    Value   Alarm Status    Alarm Type
Valve_Temp  45      0               0
```

The information on the page was originally set up to refresh via a `meta` tag every second, which isn't ideal, but was tolerable for the time being. Now we are going to start including graphs into the page, so using the `meta` tag to refresh the page is out of the question because the graph will update dynamically.

I grabbed the tag information from the original text file using this javascript function.

```
<!--Get Tag Information-->
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function getIV()
{
    AlStatusArray = new Array("No  alarm","Pretrigger","ALARM","Acknowledged","ReturnToNormal");
    AlTypeArray = new Array("None","High","Low","Level","High High","Low Low");

    IVList = new String();
    IVList = document.IVForm.fileIV.value;
    IVArray = IVList.split("\n");
    IVNum = IVArray.length;
    //alert(IVNum);

  IVLine = new String();
  for(i=1;i<IVNum-1;i++)
  {
        IVLine = IVArray[i];
        IVToken = IVLine.split(";");
        TagName = IVToken[1].replace(/(\")/g,"");
        Value = parseFloat(IVToken[2]);
        AlStatus = parseInt(IVToken[3]);
        AlType = parseInt(IVToken[4]);
    document.write("<tr><td>"+TagName+"</td><td>"+Value+"</td><td>"+AlStatusArray[AlStatus]+"</td><td>"+AlTypeArray[AlType]+"</td></tr>");
    }       
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Here is the HTML that holds the table

```html
<div id="auto">
    <table class="txt">
      <tr align="left"> 
        <th width="200">Tag Name</th>
        <th width="200">Value</th>
        <th width="200">Alarm Status</th>
        <th width="200">Alarm Type</th>
      </tr>
      <script>getIV();</script>
    </table>
    </div>
```

**This is where the new stuff begins**

I want to use this AJAX call to update the table values. I tested this call using a PHP file that had a random number generating function in it, and it worked well.

```
<!--auto refresh div-->
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#auto").load("load.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#auto").load('load.php');
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

**This is where my trouble is**

and this php script to grab the file.

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('../logs/Logfile.txt', true);
echo $file;
?>
```

Because when I grab the new information from the text file it isn't parsed in any way the information doesn't show up in the chart like it should. I attempted to put the javascript function `getIV()` into the PHP file, but it did not work.

**Question:**

Is there a way to refresh the div using a method like this? Or is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using one of the longer forms of jQuery AJAX and parsing / placing the returned data in the callback?

Comment: you can't use `document.write` after the initial page load...will overwrite the whole page. Just passing data to dom won't update a chart either without telling the chart script. Parse the data server side to format the chart script uses and use chart api to do updates

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I didn't think about that. I will attempt that.